# Gmail SSO login with different user

Tags: angular

I am working on sample program based on **Angular 13** and **angularx-social-login**. In this I need to show the **first name, last name and email id** of the logged in users in the table when login using **gmail button** is clicked.

**Problem**: The problem is when i click on login using gmail button for the first time it opens up the dialog for login credentials and display in the table but when I click the login button again instead of showing popup again for login it keeps on showing the previous login.

**Below is the code for better understanding**

**dashboard.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import {
  SocialUser,
  GoogleLoginProvider,
  SocialAuthService,
} from 'angularx-social-login';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css'],
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  reactiveForm!: FormGroup;
  user!: SocialUser;
  isSignedin!: boolean;
  userData: any = [];

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private socialAuthService: SocialAuthService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.reactiveForm = this.fb.group({
      email: ['', Validators.required],
      password: ['', Validators.required],
    });

    this.socialAuthService.authState.subscribe((user: any) => {
      debugger;
      this.user = user;
      this.isSignedin = user != null;
      if (this.user !== null && this.isSignedin !== false) {
        this.userData.push(user);
      }
      console.log(this.userData);
      this.socialAuthService.signOut();
      this.isSignedin = false;
    });
  }

  googleSignin(): void {
    this.socialAuthService.signIn(GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID);
  }

  logout(): void {
    this.socialAuthService.signOut();
  }
}
```

**dashboard.component.html**

```
<div class="container" style="max-width: 500px">

  <button type="button" (click)="googleSignin()" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Signin with Google</button>

  <div *ngIf="isSignedin === true" class="mt-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>First Name</label>
      <input type="text" [value]="user.firstName" class="form-control" id="firstname" readonly>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" [value]="user.lastName" class="form-control" id="lastname" readonly>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Email</label>
      <input type="text" [value]="user.email" class="form-control" id="email" readonly>
    </div>
    <!-- <button type="button" (click)="logout()" class="btn btn-primary">Log Out</button> -->
  </div>

</div>

<div class="container">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">First Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Email</th>
        <!-- <th scope="col">Image</th> -->
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let data of userData">
        <td>{{data.firstName}}</td>
        <td>{{data.lastName}}</td>
        <td>{{data.email}}</td>
        <!-- <td><img src={{data.photoUrl}} alt="Image"></td> -->
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

**Screenshots**

[image: First Time Login]

[image: Details getting displayed in the table]

[image: Clicking Sign in with Google again]

[image: Same Details instead of showing popup for login]

**Any solution please ?**

Answer (score 1):

that happning because of you are already logedin try to logout then agian go with the flow may this simple solution will work for you.